# NoClassDefFoundError When Using AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-appcompat

I had a project on Eclipse with many library projects. Then I moved them to Android Studio. Made gradle build successful after a hard work. Now I can run my project and install the apk to the device. But I got a NoClassDefFoundError at run time when I opened an activity that extends AppCompatActivity. But if I use Activity instead of AppCompatActivity, the error doesn't occur. I defined the activity in manifest.

Here it is the logcat output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.packagename.activities.MyActivity
at com.my.packagename.activities.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:163)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here it is my deoencencies of the module that have the activities:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

What am I missing?

Edit my manifest file:

```
...
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_activity"/>
</application>
```

And my style file:

```
 ...
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"</style>
```

Here is my activity that extends AppCompatActivity (actullaty a very simple activity) :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }
}
```

And the code where I opened this activity. I put the onClick listener code only, because whole activity is too long to put here:

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!getIsOnline()) {
            toast.setText(R.string.no_network);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Ok. I removed multidex. I put google play services with only gcm package and this solved my method count problem. gradle build file is updated. After that I run 'gradlew clean' and also 'Invalidate caches / Restart' . But the problem continues.

Comment: show your manifest.. and please dont use play-services... just dont.. it cause your app dex problem.. use individual dependencies instead

Comment: Upgrade PlayService 7.8 to 9.8 or above and user individual dependacies

Comment: try changing that `getApplicationContext()` to `CurrentActivity.this`

Answer (score 1):

- Check your theme, it should be `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` or sth.
- Check if your `MyActivity` exists on Manifest
- Check for your [method count](https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded), if it is more than 65k, make sure you use Multidex

Comment: @buttib then check for multidex as other answers stated, you can use plugin written here

Comment: I put code. There are no error in code after and before build. I got the error in runtime. @Jemshit

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle

should be a higher gradle version

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Application.Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Change grade.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

1.Try File->Invalidate caches and restart studio.

2.Add multiDexEnabled = true in your default Config

3. Add compile com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 in your dependencies
4. Application class extend MultiDexApplication instead of just Application

5.If the above thing doesn't work delete your gradle and make a clean project ,it will generate a new gradle.

Comment: I appiled your steps and none of them help me.

Comment: have you use Multidex extends Application class

Comment: I didn't have. I ll try but can you explain what is the relation between multidex and AppCompatActivity or com.android.support:appcompat-v7?

Comment: Mutidex is used to enlarge the heap size and accept  the third party with larger size.

Comment: @ pradeep yes I didn't add to my application class. When I do it, the error didn't go. I am still confused about the relation between this problem?

Answer (score 1):

in your build.gradle add

```
defaultConfig {
...
multiDexEnabled true
...
}
```

and add in your activity's onCreate

```
 MultiDex.install(this);
```

extends your application from MultiDexApplication

Comment: and extends your application from MultiDexApplication

Comment: Do you really think that the problem is about multi dex option? Because I have 'multiDexEnabled true'

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: 1. add in your manifest
  <application
        ...
        android:name=".YourApplication"
        ...
        >
        
    </application>

and add this class if you use default application  
class YourApplication extends MultidexApplicationContext {
}